# Having a problem with this error

Tags: php, mysql

Im getting this error..
**Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\inc\class.core.php on line 34**

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table." LIKE '".$column."'")) == 1)
    return TRUE;
else
    return FALSE;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Comment: @JohnConde: That question is itself marked as duplicate -- should be marked as duplicate of the one that is not.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table." LIKE '".$column."'")
```

is appareantly not returning a resource, but a boolean. The manual will tell you (i presume) that it returns false in case of an error.

So that query returned an error.... run it seperately instead of in one line for clearity. run it like this

```
mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table." LIKE '".$column."'") or die("error")
```

Look up in the manual how to put the mysql error in that `die()`.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_query() is returning false. It means the SQL query returns no rows as result. You should modify your code to

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table." LIKE '".$column."'");
if($result){
  $number_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
  echo "The table has $number_rows columns with this name";
} else {
  echo "No columns with this name";
}
```